# Sockets: clients exit without any return when server shuts down

Tags: sockets, tcp, send, recv

I'm making a simple client/server TCP communication stream and my problem is that when I kill the server app, the client app just exits gracefully. There's no output to STDERR, and recv() doesn't return 0 or -1, the client app just stops.

On the other hand, if I kill the client app, the server app gets return values of 0 from send(), which is expected.

Any help in this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does recv return, if not 0 or -1? It is a little hard to tell what is going on. On the one hand, you say that the client 'exits gracefully', which sounds like the program terminates. But on the other hand, you say it 'just stops', which makes it sound like it is hanging in recv.

Comment: Also, a bit about the IO architecture you are using would be useful. Are you using blocking or non-blocking IO? If blocking, what is the flow of control between the client and server? If non-blocking, what are you using to detect readability and writability?

Comment: Show us the code that "just stops".

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to `SIGPIPE` being raised, which will happen on an attempt to write to a connection that has been closed by the other end.  By default, `SIGPIPE` will summarily terminate the process, to prevent a bunch of system resources being wasted generating output that will go nowhere.  To prevent this, you can ignore the signal:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

If you do this, the `send` call should operate as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you kill your client application, the operating system closes all its open IO handles.  When a TCP connection is closed this way, it sends a FIN to its peer.  In this regard, having your client killed is indistinguishable from having it exit gracefully.

Once a TCP connection is established, there is no notion of "client" and "server"; it's a simple, bi-directional communication channel.  The result, from a network/sockets point of view, is the same regardless of which side gets aborted.

If you're seeing differences in behavior, then it's in the programming of the two applications.  A blocking `recv()` call should return with the number of bytes that were available when the connection closed, or possibly -1 for an error.

I suggest using `strace <client program and args>` on your process to see exactly what's occurring with that system call.